# XMLStreamException: The namespace URI has not been bound to a prefix,IBM jre

Tags: java, websphere, stax

My project working fine with tomcat server and now I am trying to run project on WebSphere Liberty Profile(WLP) but its giving me below error for stax implementation

```
     javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: The namespace URI "http://www.example.com/ns1" has not bound to a prefix.
  at  com.ibm.xml.xlxp.api.stax.msg.StAXMessageProvider.throwXMLStreamException(StAXMessageProvider.java:59)
  at com.ibm.xml.xlxp.api.stax.XMLStreamWriterBase.writeAttribute(XMLStreamWriterBase.java:464)
  at com.ibm.xml.xlxp.api.stax.XMLOutputFactoryImpl$XMLStreamWriterProxy.writeAttribute(XMLOutputFactoryImpl.java:157)
  at org.apache.olingo.odata2.core.ep.producer.XmlMetadataProducer.writeAnnotationAttributes(XmlMetadataProducer.java:599)
  at org.apache.olingo.odata2.core.ep.producer.XmlMetadataProducer.writeMetadata(XmlMetadataProducer.java:134)
```

i have set the classloader policy to parent-last in WLP.
how to implement stax in IBM jre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is resolved,thanks for your reply.
Here is solution:I have added stax2-api and woodstox-core-asl jar into my project and set below property in my project system.properties

```
javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory=com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxOutputFactory
javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory=com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory
```

Answer (score 2):

The IBM JRE does include STAX, it is required as part of Java SE.

The Javadoc for [writeAttribute](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamWriter.html#writeAttribute(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) suggests that this exception is expected if you're writing an attribute with a namespace that you haven't yet bound to a prefix. Without more information about the document you're intending to write, I can't confirm whether this is the case.

If that is the case, you either need to fix the document you're writing so that it does set a prefix for the namespace before you use the namespace, or set the `javax.xml.stream.isRepairingNamespaces` property on your output factory to `true` before creating your XMLStreamWriter.

Following the example in the Javadoc:

`xmlOutputFactory.setProperty(XMLOutputFactory.IS_REPAIRING_NAMESPACES, new Boolean(true));`

I don't know why this would work on tomcat but not liberty. More information on IBM's STAX implementation is available in the [Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYKE2_8.0.0/com.ibm.java.aix.80.doc/user/xml/xlxpj_reference.html).